# How can I remove brackets from individual (multiple) elements in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file which consists of text written in multiple (150+) rows and in  same column only.

In order to convert that text into list, I wrote this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_table('test.csv', sep =',')
text = df.values
print(text)
```

This is the output:

```
 [['abc']
  ['xyz']
  ['how are you']
  ['Hello']]
```

**Issue with the output:**

*Each element is individually within square brackets, and there are no commas to separate each element.*

The output I want/expect:

```
['abc',
 'xyz',
 'how are you',
 'Hello']
```

**AIM:**

My aim is to read elements row by row from a csv file and also make sure that they are read as mentioned in the EXPECTED output.

Comment: *Each element is individually within square brackets, and there are no commas to separate each element.* Not sure to understand this sentence, can you provide a sample of `test.csv` please?

Comment: df.values.flatten()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 1 column in your Dataframe, you can use iloc and tolist().

```
df.iloc[:,0].tolist()
Out[677]: ['abc', 'xyz', 'how are you', 'Hello']
```

If you have multiple columns in your Dataframe, use the following:

```
df['your_column_name'].tolist()
Out[677]: ['abc', 'xyz', 'how are you', 'Hello']
```